# The science of Dr Strange's magic shoes

Tags: technology, humans, clothing

Is there a difference in pressure between when a person brings their foot down and when they start to actually step?

It's worded horribly but the context would be a pair of shoes that, with hand waving, can create a normal force that can support the user, allowing them to walk in air.  But if I want the shoes to work inherently they have to know when a person wants the force and when they don't or else they just end up climbing forever.  The story involves these such shoes being available for sale, but I don't know if the characters would need to hold buttons, use neural control etc. to trigger the "platform" or if the shoes could do all the work.

Is there a significant pressure difference that a person exerts with their foot when they are bringing their foot down (before hitting ground) vs when they hit ground and start to actually put their weight on the foot?

Comment: Do you mean the kick off of the step?

Comment: Suddenly I want to apply for a government research grant, get a couple high-speed cameras, install a bunch of pressure pads in various places in several types of shoes, connect them to a data logging computer, hire some assistance and some research subjects, and so on.

Comment: I'm not clear what are you actually asking here and how are you building *new* fictional world with this information. Are you sure you didn't meant o ask this on [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) or on [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) stack?

Comment: @Mołot It would be off topic on SFF. Not sure about Movies & TV.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is *wiggles fingers mysteriously* magic.

Comment: @Bellerophon may be. But I believe it is off topic here - *if* he is asking what I guess he is. But I'm not sure, and thus voted unclear instead.

Comment: @cobaltduck I'm done something similar. Running analysis is less than exciting.

Comment: I think he is asking if their is a pressure difference between moving the foot down and hitting the ground but I'm not sure. If that is what you are asking could you edit to make it more clear?

Comment: I think I understand what you are asking.  I think you are wondering how the shoe would know if you are lowering your foot to a pseudo-step in mid air versus lowering your foot to an actual step on the ground. . .

Comment: . . . The difference would be that as the foot is coming down, but has not touched the ground yet, the only real force is probably gravity acting downward and maybe some muscle movement (ask that gait engineer guy). But when the foot touches the ground, the downward force would be the same as before but with the added weight of the person's body.  This weight would be more or less constantly changing as the person gradually transferred his full weight onto it for his other footstep.

Comment: Then there is a second force of the ground as it must react with an upward resistive force equal to the amount of weight applied to that foot.

Comment: I knew this was going to be closed.  Just as I was finishing my answer.  Crap!

Comment: Look - are the shoes magic or aren't they? If they're magic, what are messing around with science for? Or are you trying to wimp out with "well, maybe they're magic and maybe it's just good technology"?

Answer (score 4):

Your shoes engage their anti-gravitation when they are substantially level, as in the natural motion of a human step. This would make it easy and intuitive to control.

You could have them engage at a particular altitude, but the user would have to indicate whether they want to climb, travel level, or descend, perhaps by curling toes up or down.

I'm an engineer and I have studied human gaits for a real-world hyper-shoe design.

Answer (score 1):

Let it be a not-quite natural motion.

I would hate to waste magic shoes' power climbing real stairs. And that's the least obnoxious false positive. False positives could be interesting, but would not be viable in real product.

All you really need is a signal to turn them on at the right place, and use taking the weight off as a turn off signal. More control might be better in some cases but simple is probably the core of cool here. Pressing a toe button or doing some subtle ankle motion or weight shifting could be pretty clear signals if your users can reliably be expected to use them correctly.